# How do I select rows with max date, which is less than other date?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm having hard times writing this T-SQL query, so I'd appreciate some help.

There is a table that looks like this:

> id  | idd (number) | created_on (datetime) | property | old_value | new_value | ... other

This is a history log reflecting changes made to fields of some objects.

What I need to be able to do is to choose for every object the latest state of its given property to a given date.

Suppose the data looks like this:

```
 
 1 | 10 | 2014-01-01 | 14 | null | 5  
 2 | 10 | 2014-01-03 | 14 | 5    | 10  
 3 | 10 | 2014-01-05 | 14 | 10   | 8  
 4 | 11 | 2014-01-02 | 14 | null | 7  
 5 | 11 | 2014-01-08 | 14 | 7    | 25  
 ...
```

This way if I have to select the latest states of property `14` at `2014-01-10`, the result would be:

```
 3 | 10 | 2014-01-05 | 14 | 10   | 8  
 5 | 11 | 2014-01-08 | 14 | 7    | 25
```

If I have to select the latest states of property `14` at `2014-01-04`, the result would be:

```
 2 | 10 | 2014-01-03 | 14 | 5    | 10
 4 | 11 | 2014-01-02 | 14 | null | 7
```

What I've managed so far is to select the required values for a single object, which is quite easy, but I don't know how to extend the query to include all of them.

Comment: @YuriyRozhovetskiy, yes, there may be unlimited number of records per idd each day. It is actually stored as a timestamp with `ms` precision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `ROW_NUMBER()`

```
DECLARE @as_of_date DATE = '2014-01-04'

;WITH cte AS ( 
    SELECT  [id], [idd], [created_on], [property], [old_value], [new_value], rn=ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY idd ORDER BY created_on DESC)
    FROM    YourTable
    WHERE created_on <= @as_of_date
)
SELECT  *
FROM    cte
WHERE rn = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use either common table expression or subquery:

```
;WITH CTE1 (created_on, idd)
AS (
    SELECT MAX(created_on), idd 
    FROM Table_1 
    WHERE created_on < @DateTo
    GROUP BY idd)
SELECT t1.* FROM Table_1 t1
INNER JOIN CTE1 ON t1.created_on = CTE1.created_on and t1.idd = CTE1.idd
ORDER BY idd;


SELECT * FROM Table_1 t1
WHERE t1.created_on = (SELECT MAX(created_on) FROM Table_1 t2 where t1.idd = t2.idd AND created_on < @DateTo)
ORDER BY idd;
```